# Working with Events and Listeners in multiple databases in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, event-listener

I have main database with some tables and for every client we have different databases.While using events and listeners where do I specify the connection string to use.For model and controller I have used Config:set to change my connection string dynamically for one request.I added the same in the listeners handle method,but that isn't working and the events shows as failed.

Thanks in advance.
The Listener method.

```
public function handle(ApplicationAssociated $event)
{   
    echo "Hi";
    $client_id=$event->client_id;
    echo 'hiii'.$client_id;
    $dbconnections=DBConnection::where('client_id',$client_id)->get();
    if($client_id>0)
    {

        foreach($dbconnections as $dbconnection)
        {
            echo "in if the db name is".$dbconnection->mysql_database;
            echo "break";
            if($dbconnection->mysql_password==NULL)
             {
                 $password="";
             }
             else
             {
                 $password=$dbconnection->password;
             }
             \Config::set([
                 'database.connections.mysql1.host' => $dbconnection->mysql_host,
                 'database.connections.mysql1.database' => $dbconnection->mysql_database,
                 'database.connections.mysql1.username' => $dbconnection->mysql_username,
                 'database.connections.mysql1.password' => $password,
            ]);    
        }

    }

    echo \Config::get('database.connections.mysql1.database');

    Application::where('id',21)
    ->update(['name' =>'Testing eventing']);
    echo "LAST";

}
```

Comment: Often (in my case) in the listeners their is not much code, maybe you could use the `DB` facade and [specify the connection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#using-multiple-database-connections) for each query. But again, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish exactly. How do you events and listeners look? Could you share the code, as well as the errors of your failed events.

Comment: How to make the events and listeners work for specific  connection strings.In the handle method I have specified the connection to use .

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

config/database.php

```
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver'         => 'mysql',
        'host'           => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
        'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
        'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
        'unix_socket'    => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset'        => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation'      => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'         => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict'         => true,
        'engine'         => null,
        'options'        => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

.env file

```
DB_DATABASE2=ichuztowork
DB_USERNAME2=root
DB_PASSWORD2=
```

Anywhere in your application you can set the connection string in this way

```
$user = (new \App\User(['name'=>'My Name', 'email'=>'myEmail@email.com']))- 
>setConnection('foreignDB');
$user->save();

// or if you don't need to use the model, then just
(new \App\User(['name'=>'My Name', 'email'=>'myEmail@email.com']))- 
>setConnection('foreignDB')->save();
```